# Django. Перевод значений в верхний регистр при создании объекта модели

Tags: python, django, база-данных, веб-программирование

У меня есть модель, которая хранит в себе полное и краткое название криптомонеты. Название монет - это уникальное значение, которое не может повторятся. Однако когда я зашёл в админ-панель и попытался создать монету, я заметил, что могу создать две одинаковых монеты: `btc` и `BTC`.

Я понимаю, что для `django` - это разные названия из-за регистра, поэтому она допускает их создание. Хотелось бы узнать, как можно решить эту проблему.

Я пытался решить эту проблему на моменте описания полей модели. Я создал класс, который наследуется от `CharField`, но я не понимаю, где мне надо менять регистр.

Также я попытался изменить метод `save`, но при добавлении похожей записи `django` выкидывает исключение `IntegrityError`, хотя без переопределения этого метода, в интерфейсе админ-панели появлялось сообщение "Это название уже есть".

`models.py`:

```
class CryptoCoin(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.short_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно переопределить метод `save` таким образом:

```
class CryptoCoin(models.Model):
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
        short_name = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.short_name = self.short_name.upper()
            return super(CryptoCoin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Так же, как вариант, можно попробовать переопределить `field` модели:

```
class UpperField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpperField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return str(value).upper()

class CryptoCoin(models.Model):
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
        short_name = UpperField(max_length=5, unique=True)
```

Comment: Второй способ подошёл. Спасибо :)